# Leaving the US on a foreign passport with no entry stamp/visa? For dual citizens

Tags: dual-nationality

I am a dual citizen MEX/US. So I have a US and a Mexican passport. My US passport needs to be out of commission for a matter of weeks, and I need to exit the US during that time for travel. I am wondering if I can leave the US on my Mexican passport although it has no stamps in it currently

Comment: I plan to fly out

Answer (score 2):

**This is fine**. The US doesn't have exit checks, so you won't be subject to questioning or anything when you leave. The airline (if you're flying) will check your passport, so make sure you're going to a country you can enter visa-free as a Mexican citizen (or apply for a visa).

Entering the US, you're legally obliged to use a US passport (or Enhanced Drivers' License, Passport Card etc. if you're crossing by land).

Comment: The point about entering is potentially very important.

Comment: While you are legally obliged to use your US passport, immigration is even more obliged to let you in, passport or not.  They may delay you and give you a hard time but they can't refuse entry. The more evidence you have that you are actual a US citizen, the qicker it will go.

Comment: "Entering the US, you're legally obliged to use a US passport" Actually, a US citizen is *legally* obliged to be bearing a US passport when both entering *and leaving* the US. However, there is no penalty for violating this law.

Comment: @user102008 in the unlikely event of a spot check, however (see the recent question [How come I was asked by a CBP officer why I was in the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/140701/19400)), the traveler could be prevented from boarding the flight.